# In Virtualmin, change the directory of a cookieless subdomain (subserver) to that of the main site

Tags: virtualhost, webmin

I want to make a cookieless subdomain in virtualmin. I make a subserver for my main domain server. I want the subserver to has the same home directory as the main server but i can't find how to put a directory that exist.